# Muxing DVD to Mpeg TS

Tags: video, dvd, encoding, mpeg

I am looking for good software to generate a MPEG transport stream from DVDs and other MPEG2 files.
I have tried with ffmpeg but it produces broken streams.

Preferably Linux software but Windows is fine too. Free or commercial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) will do this and much, much more.

It's [open source and cross platform](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/index.php?title=Avidemux)

> **Avidemux** is a free  open-source 
>   program designed for multi-purpose
>   video editing and processing.
>   Downloads, documentation, and other
>   features can be found at avidemux.org.
>   It is written in C/C++, using the GTK+
>   graphics toolkit, and therefore is
>   truly a platform independent,
>   universal video processing program. It
>   is available for almost all
>   distributions of Linux that are
>   capable of compiling C/C++, GTK+ and
>   the SpiderMonkey  ECMAScript scripting
>   engine. A Win32 version of this
>   program is also available for Windows
>   users, as well as Mac OS X, FreeBSD,
>   NetBSD, and OpenBSD  ports and
>   packages. The program can be run in
>   64bit operating systems that are
>   non-Windows and non-Macintosh based.

Info on [Input Formats](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/index.php?title=Input_formats) and [Output Formats](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/index.php?title=Output_formats)